# How to do a lookup between string field and ObjectId - MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have these collections:

1 - Order:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac68963b305462bc88150f6"), 
    "ClientId" : "5aabc24bb3054633a4053a9f" 
}
```

2 - Client:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aabc24bb3054633a4053a9f"), 
    "Name" : "Tiago", 
    "Email" : "tiago@email.com", 
}
```

I want to bring in Order, the data from Client. But because ClientId is a string and the _id in Client is an ObjectId I can't do the lookup between then.

I'm doing with MongoDB C# Driver, this is my code until now:

```
var order = _database.GetCollection<Order>.Aggregate().Match(myFilter).Lookup("Client", "ClientId", "_id", "MyPropertyToFill").As<Order>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Any idea about how to do this?

Comment: So you want to find a client's order, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, you have to define iClientId as an ObjectId as follow:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const Order = new Schema({
  iClientId: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  // Rest of the Field
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('order', Order)
```

Now In your file where you want to do a lookup

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId

Model.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: ObjectId('filter_id')}},
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'client',
    localField: 'ClientId',
    foreignFiled: '_id',
    as: 'fromclient'
  }}
], (err, result) => {
 // Your action
})
```

This how you can achieve that, I have done it with mongoose but you can do it without mongoose as well.

Comment: This was what I did. I changed the type of ClientId with this script and now my query works: db.Order.find({}).forEach( function (x) {   
  x.ClientId = new ObjectId(x.ClientId);
  db.Order.save(x);
});